# Regex: Matching a part of last part of URL?

Tags: regex

I have a lot lines like this:

```
<b>http://www.mywebsite.com/video/xvxkxf_article1_something</b>
<b>http://www.mywebsite.com/video/xvxkxi_article2_something</b>
```

How to match "article1_something" and "article2_something" ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (entire) regex matches your target

```
(?<=_)\w*
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/AMJA9H7nLg)

The entire match is your target - no need to sully yourself with groups.

Comment: Your code work great ! However, if my url: <b>http://www.mywebsite.com/video/xvxkxf_article1-article2-articlen_something</b>, how to match "article1-article2-articlen_something" ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
.*?_(.*)</b>$
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yP3iB0/4

or

```
^.*?_|</b>
```

Try this.Replace with `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yP3iB0/5

Comment: Hello, Your code work great. However, I edited my question. Sorry, it is my mistake. Now, it has </b> in the end of sentence. How to fix it ?

Comment: Change the regex pattern to `.*?_(.*)<b>$`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex free version:

```
<?php
$str = "<b>http://www.mywebsite.com/video/xvxkxf_article1_something</b>";
$str = substr($str, 0, strlen($str) - 4); // removing </b>
$ar = explode("/", $str); // break url into array with / as delimiter
$ending_path = end($ar); // xvxkxf_article1_something
$ending_path_ar = explode("_", $ending_path); // break xvxkxf_article1_something with _ as delimiter
array_shift($ending_path_ar); // remove xvxkxf

$res = implode("_", $ending_path_ar); // join together pieces with _ as glue.

echo $res; // article1_something
?>
```

Comment: I hope this is a PHP question, otherwise this'd be immaterial.

Comment: Well the guy didn't specify what language it is, and since PHP is predominantly used...

Comment: You must be fun at parties :p

Comment: Yeah, well, I wasn't really fond of the solution since it doesn't bring the simplicity of what you could achieve with a one-liner regex, but after I went and rethink I guess I'll let you live. :P

Answer (score 0):

Here's your regex:

```
/article\d_something/
```